# Using shell versus eshell whenever an Emacs action needs to spawn a shell in a new buffer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, emacs, eshell, rinari

I'm using Rinari for Rails development in Emacs.  M-x shell will open a new buffer that is correctly PATH'd for my environment (zsh).  M-x eshell uses all the incorrect PATH's and I haven't been able to get it to play nicely with anything.

There's a function of Rinari that fires up an instance of a web server for the Rails app I'm editing, however, but the buffer it opens with the server instance is eshell.

How can I ultimately get this to open a buffer using shell (or what would open with M-x shell) instead?

Below is the defun for the command I'm trying to execute.

Is there simply a setting I can change or a variable that looks for what shell to open?

```
(defun rinari-web-server (&optional edit-cmd-args)
  "Run script/server.  Dump output to a compilation buffer
   allowing jumping between errors and source code.  With optional
   prefix argument allows editing of the server command arguments."
  (interactive "P")
  (let* ((default-directory (rinari-root))
        (script (concat (expand-file-name "server"
                   (file-name-as-directory
                    (expand-file-name "script" (rinari-root))))
         (if rinari-rails-env (concat " -e " rinari-rails-env))))
 (command (if edit-cmd-args
          (read-string "Run Ruby: " (concat script " "))
        script)))
(ruby-compilation-run command)) (rinari-launch))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to alias 'emacs' to launch Emacs.app and in doing so from my terminal environment, Emacs then carries over the appropriate PATH inside eshell.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find anything to configure, you can always try something like the following:

```
(defun fooby ()
  ""
  (interactive)
  (eshell))

(defadvice fooby (around fooby-replace-eshell-with-shell-around act)
  "Substitute `shell` for `eshell` for the duration of this call"
  (flet ((eshell () (shell)))
    ad-do-it))
```

For the duration of the call to `fooby` it will substitute a call to `shell` any time `eshell` is called.  You want to focus the advice as tightly as possible, so if you can find the function that actually calls `eshell`, that would be the one to advise.  Of course, if you don't feel like digging, you can always just advise `rinari-web-server`.  If you never, ever want to use `eshell`, then you can use `fset` to do the substitution globally:

```
(fset 'eshell 'shell)
```

Hope that helps!